# Skip image missing routing error in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I regularly imports some tables from the production to development environment. One table is related to images, and when I run development, these images all causes `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/xxx.jpg"):`.

The listing pages show lots of these images, which flooded my log. I am wondering if one can skip the logging of these routing error (for missing images only) in the development environment?

I have tried using `rescue_from` but it does not seem to work, and it is not fine-grain enough.

Answer (score -1):

The new configuration level changes are not applied until server is restarted. Restarting the server should apply new routes. Also share the result of `$ rake routes` in terminal.

Comment: My question is not about route in particular. I want to skip the logging of route-missing error for images which live under the public folder.